# Why these lists are not getting modified?

Tags: python, list, rounding

I have 2 lists with fractions:

```
lst1 = [.2568123, .3589123]
lst2 = [.5689123, .6547123]
```

I want to round all of them in one code block. So I tried:

```
for lst in [lst1, lst2]:        
    lst = [round(x,1) for x in lst]
```

I check lists now:

```
print(lst1, lst2)
```

However, I find the lists still contain same values, not rounded values:

```
[0.2568123, 0.3589123] [0.5689123, 0.6547123]
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: why you assign to the same iter var?

Comment: `lst` is a reference to the lists `lst1` or `lst2`. By assigning that reference you're modifying what `lst` points to but not the original itself.

Comment: Because *nowhere* do you modify the list. This is the same as `data = []; x = data; x = [42]; print(data)`. You assign a new list to `lst`, but that won't affect any of the other lists you've created. Assignment *never* mutates. see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Now, you *could* do `lst[:] = [round(x,1) for x in lst]` since indexing-assgnment *does* mutate. But not simple assignment. That simply binds a name to an object

Comment: Why negative votes? It's a tricky issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code, lst has same name at two points ,but,they are different(identity is different).you can check it by,

```
lst1 = [.2568123, .3589123]
lst2 = [.5689123, .6547123]
for lst in [lst1, lst2]:     
    print(id(lst)) #a
    lst = [round(x,1) for x in lst]
    print(id(lst)) #b a!=b
```

You can try this,

```
lst1 = [.2568123, .3589123]
lst2 = [.5689123, .6547123]
for lst in lst1,lst2:
    for x,y in enumerate(lst):lst[x]=round(y,1)
    
print(lst1,lst2)
```

Comment: Really ,identity is different.

Comment: It is surprising (almost inconsistent) that modifying `lst` does not modify original (`lst1` and `lst2`) but modifying `lst[0]` does modify `lst1[0]` and `lst2[0]`

Comment: lst is a reference to lst1 and lst2.when call lst[0],it is a reference to lst1[0] and lst2[0].Therefore,if lst[0] is modified ,it means lst1[0] and lst2[0] is modified.But,when assigning another list to lst, It is not still referring to lst1 and lst2.